# Trying to get all fields in a Socrata python API call

Tags: python, socrata

I am using the python api (sodapy) to get data from https://dev.socrata.com/foundry/data.energystar.gov/ebvx-pb7r. How do I get all the fields shown on this page through the api? Specifically, I need the additional_model_information field, though I think there will be others. I have tried:

1. "where additional_model_information is not null": the field is included, but I also want the rows that have null.
2. "select='additional_model_information' the field is returned, but nothing else.
3. "select=*" does not add any fields.
4. "where='additional_model_information is not null or additional_model_information is null'" This seems to work.
5. "select=list all fields" Should work, but seems unwieldy.
6. Could make 2 calls, one to get the * data and a second to get other fields.

I suspect I am missing something. Any help is appreciated.

```
import pprint
import sodapy

client = sodapy.Socrata(domain='data.energystar.gov', app_token=None)
rows = client.get('ebvx-pb7r', where='additional_model_information is not null or additional_model_information is null')
for row in rows:
    pprint.pprint(row)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just leave off the `where` parameter entirely, you'll an unfiltered version of the dataset, which it sounds like is what you want. You'll also want to include the `limit` parameter to make sure you get all of the records, since the total count is `1058`, which is larger than the default page size of `1000`:

```
import pprint
import sodapy

client = sodapy.Socrata(domain='data.energystar.gov', app_token=None)
rows = client.get('ebvx-pb7r', limit=5000)
for row in rows:
    pprint.pprint(row)
```

I think part of the confusion may come from the fact that if there is no value for `additional_model_information` for a given record, the JSON object that we return will omit that field.

Comment: Thanks. So any field that is null in the db will not be in the json results for that row.